# A generalization of the Euler-Mascheroni constant

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, euler-mascheroni-constant

Let $f:[1,+\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function. We are dealing with the limit of the sequence 
$$
f(n)-\sum_{k=1}^nf'(k).
$$
If $f=\log$, then it is convergent to $-\gamma$ (where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant). Now,

(a) Are there some criteria for its convergence (by putting some conditions on $f$)?

(b) Does anyone know some references (paper, book, etc.) about it?

Comment: Are you familiar with the Euler-Maclaurin summation formula?

Comment: Yes, I know it.

Comment: You may be able to build a set of convergence criteria from the error bounds that are part of that formula.